# Google Now menu flashes quickly

Tags: google-now

I have a Galaxy Note 2.

When I go to Google Now and use the soft key to access its menu to get to the settings, the menu just flashes. I can't get it to stay on the screen long enough to hit the settings button. I tried to uninstall and reinstall it, but it still does the same thing.